# php excel reader date format getting 1970-01-30 for any input date given in excel sheet

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

I'am getting date format as 1970-01-30 for any input date given date in excel

There are two fields having with date format cells for any date given in excel it is showing as 1970-01-30 as output in echo

please can any one help me

```
This is my code


public function clientfileupload($list_id){
    $clientarr = array('client_name','client_nick_name', 'client_email','client_phone','client_address','client_location','contract_name','contract_description','contract_value','renewal_date','expiry_date','payment_mode');
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
    $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"];
    $filetype = explode(".",$name);
    $name = str_replace(' ', '',$name. "_" . time());
    $abs = getcwd();
    $path = $abs . "/upload/excelfiles/";
    $pathfile = $path . $name;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"], $path . $name))
    if($filetype[1] == 'xlsx')
    {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($pathfile);
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F' 
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    }
    else 
    {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($pathfile);
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F' 
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    }
    $notinserted = array();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) 
    {
        $arr = array();
        for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex - 1; ++$col) 
        {

            if($col == 9 || $col == 10)
            {
                $rowname = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue()));
            }else
            {
                $rowname =  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
            }
            if ($row != 1) 
            {
                $arr[$clientarr[$col]] = $rowname;
            }
        }         
    }
    print_r($arr);exit;           
    echo true;
    exit;
}
```

can any one help me thank you in advance

Comment: What is the value of the cell you run this code on?

Comment: in echo $arr im getting this output                                                                             "Array
(
    [client_name] => gdfg
    [client_nick_name] => yuy
    [client_email] => iuu@iu.on
    [client_phone] => 988654656
    [client_address] => iouioyuftiy
    [client_location] => uyuty
    [contract_name] => huyty
    [contract_description] => yutfugvhjbkj
    [contract_value] => 89544
    [renewal_date] => 1900-01-12
    [expiry_date] => 1900-01-12
    [payment_mode] => QUA
)
"

Comment: There is no `echo $arr` in your code. But either way... that was not my question. What is the value in the excelsheet you run this code on?

Comment: i have given todays date for expiry_date and renewal_date but it is showing 1900-01-30 for both in output

Comment: Dude... This is getting boring... WHAT IS THE VALUE?! Take a screenshot, take a photo with your phone, or copy paste! Seriously, What is the value?! No words trying to explain, it's a simple question

Comment: $clientarr = array('client_name','client_nick_name', 'client_email','client_phone','client_address','client_location','contract_name','contract_description','contract_value','renewal_date','expiry_date','payment_mode');
        $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"];
        $filetype = explode(".",$name);
        $name = str_replace(' ', '',$name. "_" . time());
        $abs = getcwd();
        $path = $abs . "/upload/excelfiles/";
        $pathfile = $path . $name;

Comment: $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($pathfile);
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F' 
            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

Comment: andreas plz help me i added image for u